# How should I interpret 最大限度 in 我们最大限度地利用现有港口条件运货?

Tags: meaning

> 我们最大限度地利用现有港口条件运货。

I think I should treat 最大限度地 as one word, namely 'maximally‘. Does that fit?

Rough draft; not good English:

> We maximally exploit current harbour conditions transport goods.

Final interpretation:

> We make maximum use of the currently existing harbour conditions to transport goods.

Comment: As much as we can/as much as possible.

Comment: Some users would like to remind OP that there are online dictionaries (e.g.iciba)that will provide the needed translation. How about feeding＂ 最大限度＂into iciba？有使用者想提醒OP，有在线的词典（例如爱词霸）会提供必要的翻译。 把＂ 最大限度＂输入iciba怎么样。

Comment: `最大限度` is a common phrase rather than a word. Both your interpretations are good and valid.

Comment: Why use 'some users', try saying 'I'! That must be you ree_o! Guten Tag!
dj.iciba.com/最大限度-1.html

Answer (score 3):

We exploit the current harbour conditions transport goods to the largest extent.
Here "to the largest extent" means 最大限度地.

Comment: Thanks, but your English needs polishing!'to the largest extent' is how we exploit, not how we transport. 

We exploit current harbour conditions to the fullest to move our goods.